# Ocultar "PERFIL" na aba visualizar do PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

alguém sabe como escondo essa parte Perfil no PhpMyadmin?
Já mexi em tudo aqui, tentei resetar as configurações padrões e nada!

[image: PhpMyadmin Versão 4.0.10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você apertou na seleção para não exibir?

[image]

Comment: Era isso, não vi, obrigado!

Comment: Tamo junto irmão